# conversion of datetime field(in json object) to milliseconds using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I have a JSON object which has a datetime field like below -

```
2019-02-10T07:17:42.236Z
```

I have retrieved this field onto my angular component using the code below -

```
this.filteredVenues.forEach(ven => console.log(ven.lastheartbeat));
```

When i tried to convert the datetime format above to milliseconds using the code below -

```
this.filteredVenues.forEach(ven => console.log(ven.lastheartbeat.getTime()))
```

I get the error below -

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined
```

If i run trials on getTime() method, it works fine here -
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G12D4LYOO7IG

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show more of your code so we can see if there is a problem in it?

Comment: If `console.log(ven.lastheartbeat.getTime())` triggers that error I doubt that `console.log(ven.lastheartbeat)` prints anything. The error clearly suggests there is no `ven.lastheartbeat`.

Comment: can you show how you filtervenue looks like ?

Comment: Where do you have `ven.lastheartbeat = new Date(ven.sometimestamp)` ?

Comment: I can log ven.lastheartbeat on console. I can only share so much since since there is a data share restriction for me.   I got the solution. I modified the code like here - this.filteredVenues.forEach(ven => console.log(new Date(ven.lastheartbeat).getTime()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make you string first change to Date object to access `getTime` method. normal string do not have `getTime` method

```js
console.log((new Date('2019-02-10T07:17:42.236Z')).getTime())
```

Comment: The error he's getting states that the variable `getTime` is called on is undefined. If it were a string, it would be a different error.

Comment: @Jeto if this is the case than OP will get error in the first one itself `this.filteredVenues.forEach(ven => console.log(ven.lastheartbeat));` but op said he's getting error when he tries `this.filteredVenues.forEach(ven => console.log(ven.lastheartbeat.getTime()))`

Comment: Right, that's the weird part, as I mentioned in the comments. The variable exists in the first statement and is undefined in the second one, so somehing must have happened in between.

Answer (score 1):

I had to dummy up here.
But essentially I think you need to change:
`ven.lastheartbeat.getTime()` to `Date(ven.lastheartbeat).getTime()`

```js
// Dummy
let ven = {
  lastheartbeat: '2019-02-10T07:17:42.236Z'
};

let dte = new Date(ven.lastheartbeat);

console.log(dte.getTime());
```